# Multiple bookmark and formfields replacement from excel to word not working anymore

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, bookmarks, form-fields

Some time ago, I created this macro with vba which worked very well with Office 2003. It still works with Office 2021 as long as you don't modify the Word file. If I change it, it can no longer see the bookmark to replace. Microsoft Office Mysteries. It is important to underline that I have to replace several (100 or more) bookmarks.

An example:

```
Sub MA01()
'
' MA01 Macro
' Macro registrata il 18/12/2015 da Esterni
'

    Sheets("Lineare").Select 'go to a specific excel sheet where are the imputs


' get all the imputs from the cell (true or false value) to check or uncheck a specific formfield 
Cross01 = Range("C669").Value  ' get first value to check or uncheck a specific formfield after
Cross02 = Range("C668").Value  ' get second value to check or uncheck a specific formfield after
'continue and so on

' get all the imputs from the cell to replace after a specific bookmark 
Stringa001 = Range("C650").Value  'get first value to replace after a specific bookmark 
Stringa002 = Range("C28").Value  'get second value to replace after a specific bookmark
'continue and so on



' open a specific file word  to make the change after

Const sFILENAME As String = "C:\test\test.doc" ' file name here
Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wrdApp.Visible = True
Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open(sFILENAME)
With wrdDoc


' check or uncheck a specific formfield 
.FormFields("Controllo01").CheckBox.Value = Cross01
.FormFields("Controllo02").CheckBox.Value = Cross02
'continue and so on




' replace a specific Bookmark
.Bookmarks("X001").Range.Text = Stringa001
.Bookmarks("X002").Range.Text = Stringa002
'continue and so on

' go to a spefific sheet of excel and into a specific cell
    Sheets("Ins Dati").Select
    Range("Q68").Select
End With
MsgBox ("OK !!!! Document created")
End Sub
```

Comment: `if I change it it can no longer see the bookmark to replace.` Chang what?

Comment: Once you run that code all replaced bookmarks will be deleted.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63784914/update-the-bookmarks-from-excel/63839516#63839516 for how to avoid that.

Comment: One obvious issue is that you have created a document when you should have created a template. Instead of `Documents.Open` you should be using `Documents.Add`. Doing so would create a new document with no risk of the template content being changed.

Comment: @TimWilliams - not necessarily. Bookmarks are only deleted if they enclose text. Often users will simply insert a bookmark to mark the position that text is inserted, in which case the bookmarked range has zero length, and the text is inserted immediately after the bookmark.

Comment: @ Tim William, yes that is what i want , i want that bookmarks will be deleted with the value of a specific cell in excel. The document that i will generate will be "saved as" 
 to another name.  i use this macro to fullfill word modules, Thats it.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that the bookmark I inserted was not recognized by VBA in newer versions.
I used legacy bookmarks but for an unknown reason they were not seen, by VBA, in recent versions of Office.

To ensure that the bookmark is recognized in the most recent versions of Office you need to insert the bookmark from the drop-down menu  INSERT - Bookmarks (ICON) and then add bookmark,
THAT bookmark is seen by VBA, while the others inserted via drop-down menu development  legacy module (icon) do not work.

Big BUG for me in the new versions of office. (I spent a lot of time trying to figure out what the hell happened) Thanks MS for complicate my life.